# Hiding a button when mouse (pointing device) is not active (not moving)

Tags: javascript, html, events, button, hide

I am trying to hide a button when the mouse is not moving. That's all. I have found a solution on here but it references a Google javascript file (links directly to a javascript file on one of their hosting drives) and I would like my website to not be dependent on anything else -- I would like it to be stand-alone.

Please help!

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">>
  
     function change( el )
     {
       if ( el.value === "Display Menu" )
         el.value = "Hide Menu";
       else
         el.value = "Display Menu";
     }
  
    </script>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Display Menu" onclick="return change(this);" />
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You can replace that with a local file on your build. That's used here so the snippet will work. You can ever just include the entire JQuery script in the header of your file if you wanted,  though that'd be weird.

Answer (score 0):

This hides the button after 300ms of the mouse not moving, which is enough time to not have it flash (hiding and showing every few ms).

Best to give the button an id if possible for clarity and ease of selection.

Set the CSS for the button `to display:none;`

Button starts hidden, on move, it is set to `show()`, then the timer is ready to hide it again in 300 ms if no movement is detected. If movement is detected, the timer is reset.

```js
var timer;
$(document ).mousemove(function(){
    $("#mouseDrivenButton" ).show();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mouseDrivenButton" ).hide();
    },300)
});
```

```css
 #mouseDrivenButton {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="mouseDrivenButton">Mouse Is Moving</button>
```

**THIS ONE IS PURE JAVASCRIPT FOR YOU and requires no external scripts**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    #mouseDrivenButton {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var timer;
    document.onmousemove = function() {
      document.getElementById('mouseDrivenButton').style.display = "block";
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('mouseDrivenButton').style.display = "none";
      }, 300)
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="mouseDrivenButton">Mouse Is Moving</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I was hoping to not use Google's js file  

My post: "I have found a solution on here but it references a Google javascript file (links directly to a javascript file on one of their hosting drives) and I would like my website to not be dependent on anything else"

You may have overlooked that, but I really appreciate you taking the time to write what you did. It might help someone else!

Comment: Ok, I've added a solution above that's pure javascript with no external dependencies. In the future, it's good if you let folks know that in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you found had a jQuery part which you didn't want.

This would do, as it's pure native javascript.

```js
var el =  document.getElementById("btnMenu");
var timer;
function showBtn(){
 el.style.display = "block";
}
function hideBtn(){
 el.style.display = "none";
}

hideBtn();
document.onmousemove = function(){
   showBtn();
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(function(){
        hideBtn();
    },100)
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input id="btnMenu" type="button" value="Display Menu"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Did not work :(. Did you test that code? If so, I can keep cracking at it. I spent some time trying to figure out why it was doing nothing to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: I even tried making a fresh html file with just your code and nothing happened. 

Code:

<html>
<head>
<script type=="text/javascript">

var el =  document.getElementById("btnMenu");
var timer;
function showBtn(){
 el.style.display = "block";
}
function hideBtn(){
 el.style.display = "none";
}

hideBtn();
document.onmousemove = function(){
   showBtn();
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(function(){
        hideBtn();
    },100)
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="btnMenu" type="button" value="Display Menu"/>
</body>
</html>